# Decoupling capacitors used in a remote controlled stepper motor circuit

Tags: stepper-motor, decoupling-capacitor, stepper-driver

I am building an Arduino-based remote controller for a stepper motor-driven variable capacitor for a magnetic loop antenna to be used with an amateur radio transmitter, which will create a fairly high amount of local RFI. To prevent the RFI from getting back up the interconnecting cables, I have installed 50V 100nF ceramic decoupling capacitors on both RJ45 sockets between each core of the Cat8 screened cable and true earth. The problem I am getting is that the stepper motor just makes a noise and does not move. If I connect the stepper motor directly to the A4988 driver, the stepper works fine in both directions. The conclusion I have drawn is that the decoupling capacitors are somehow causing the operational problem. Should I reduce the value of the decoupling capacitors? What is causing the system to not work when using the Cat8 cables? Your thoughts would be most helpful.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what kind of frequencies your driver is trying to apply to the motors? I wouldn't think 100nF would be a problem unless the frequency was reasonably high (which maybe it is, I don't know)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what frequency is created by the driver.

Comment: If the driver doesn't use microstepping, then the frequency is the frequency you are sending steps. If the driver uses microstepping, the frequency should be specified in the datasheet

Comment: Thank you user253751. Yes, I am using 1/16th micro steps via the MS1, MS2 & MS3 pins. I will have to check the datasheet to obtain the frequency.

Comment: How long is the cable? What signals go over it (just step/dir)? Have a scope? Show whats going in and out of the cable.

Comment: The voltage input to the A4988 driver is 11volts and the stepper motor is rated for 12 volts. 
I have been unable to find any data relating to the frequency that the stepper driver operates at. I have checked that the Cat8 connections are both the same, style B.

Comment: The cable is 15 metres long and the resistance per core is approximately 2ohms. Just four cores are used for the stepper step/dir. Unfortuantely I do not have a scope, so I am unable to check.